# What R packages do SVM training on a GPU for Windows?

Tags: r, windows, gpu

I found that 'rpud' was not free, and that 'rgtsvmt' and 'gputools' were not able to install on Windows 10.

What alternatives remain?  For repeated testing of features, etc, the reduced runtime really matters.

(Obviously, OS change is not an option.)